# Scaling data subsetwise using R

Tags: r, dplyr, normalize

I Have the following dataset regarding a digital marketing problem. the size of the audience, no of inactive e mails read mails and the priority of the segment are given

```
 AudienceSize   inactiveemails  Readmails   Importanceof targetgroup
   246238       63581          1015         Low
    402042       609           2089         Medium
      2395        4              12         Medium
      10958       76             105        High
     120291     1237             707        Medium
      65199      0               544        Low
      106341    1506             1171       Medium
      496986    8501             3139      Medium
     293509     4805            2059        Medium
       93218     97              814       Medium
     246238     63581           1015          Low
      402042     609            2089        Medium
      2395        4              12         Medium
      10958       76             105        High
      120291    1237             707        Medium
      65199      0               544        Low
      106341    1506             1171      Medium
      496986    8501             3139      Medium
      293509    4805            2059       Medium
      93218     97               814       Medium
```

I need to scale the data.  The low priority e mails should be scaled among members low category alone. Similarly for the medium and high category, the scaling should be done using that alone. Is there anyway to achieve this.

```
Importanceoftargetgroup  AudienceSize Readmails Inactivemails
Low                          .03444     .5366     .7437
Low                          .03664     .7500     .8000
medium                        .7665      .4333    .6543
medium                        .7965      .5533    .7543
```

Note: DPLYR has helped me subset the data and get means, but I need the scaled versions.

Comment: What is the scaling factor for `AudienceSize`, `Readmails` and `Inactivemails`?

Comment: Individually, each should be scaled between 0 and 1. But it should be done such that- low priorioty is grouped between 0 and 1, medium priority between 0 and 1 and high priority between 0 and 1.

Comment: try `library(dplyr); 
df %>%
  group_by(Importanceoftargetgroup) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(scale), AudienceSize, inactiveemails, Readmails)`

Comment: It is a minmax normalization sum. We can also use z score. But the objective is that low priority e mail data columns are compared with low priority e mail values alone. similarly medium priority e mail data should be compared with itself.

Comment: Alright Sir. Will try this

Comment: Prem's solution should work

Comment: It seems to work sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the desired result using

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Importanceoftargetgroup) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(scale), AudienceSize, inactiveemails, Readmails)
```

Comment: Done. Sorry took a while to get back.